# Read only exact match data from a text file in Java

Tags: java, binary

I am trying to find out a way to extract or read just one type of content from a text file using java.

**Let's say my text file contains:**

> What's your name, 00 5 6 0 K Write your 0 9 2 Name Let's not Talk
>   about 1 1 0 5 it

Now what i want it - my java program to run and able to only find the binary values which are 1 and 0's . leaving the all other things that is in the text file and show them. Also, if possible to count the binary values.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: And what is currently the problem you're facing?

Comment: Yeah i tried something , 

package Binary;

import java.io.BufferedReader;


public class Binary {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  BufferedReader br = Binary2.openFile("src/in.txt");
  String line;
  
  while ((line = Binary2.readLine(br)) != null) {
   for (char letter : line.toCharArray()) {
    if (letter >= '0' && letter <= '1')
     System.out.print(letter + " ");
   }
   System.out.println();
  }  
 }
}

Comment: and 

package Binary;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Binary2 {
 
 public static BufferedReader openFile(String filename) {
  try { return new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)); }
  catch (IOException e) { return null; }
 }
 
 public static void closeFile(BufferedReader reader) {
  try { reader.close(); }
  catch (IOException e) { } 
 }
 
 public static String readLine(BufferedReader reader) {
  try { return reader.readLine(); } 
  catch (IOException e) { return null; }
 }
}

Comment: Your program printed: `0 0 0 0 1 1 0`. So what is the issue? Try to post the code in the main post and properly formatted (there is a "edit" button there, and also use code tags). I suggest don't leave catch blocks empty or return a `null`; use `e.printStackTrace()` to view the exception details, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am not sure what is the issue, it's not even running in my computer, i think i will give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution - The first file

```
package Binary; 
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.IOException; 

public class Read1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        BufferedReader br = Read2.openFile("src/in.txt"); 
            String line; 
                while ((line = Read2.readLine(br)) != null) 
        { 
            for (char letter : line.toCharArray()) 
            {       if (letter >= '0' && letter <= '1') 
                    System.out.print(letter + " "); 
            } System.out.println(); 
        }   
    } 
}
```

This is another file in the package,

```
package Binary; 
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.IOException; 


public class Read2 
{ 
    public static BufferedReader openFile(String filename) 
    { 
        try { 
                return new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)); 
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            { 
                return null; 
            } 

    } 

    public static void closeFile(BufferedReader reader) 

    { try 
        { 
            reader.close(); 
        } catch (IOException e) 
        { 

        } 
    } 

    public static String readLine(BufferedReader reader) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            return reader.readLine(); 
        } catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            return null; 
        }
    }

}
```

And my text files looks like :

> how are you doing
>
> 1 0 1 0 1 0
>   0 10 10 10 10  111 0100 1 111
>
> Man01 No932 
>   53 53 46 4 2
>
> 33 0 0 3

And the Output Result was :

```
1 0 1 0 1 0 
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 
1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 
0 1  
0 0
```

Now to further improve the program I also want to print how many times the program found both 0's and 1's in the text file. Basically, the total occurrences.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, Just change the first file, Read1 - What i did there was made the count with count++ for 0's and c++ for 1's . Hope it helps.

```
package Binary; 
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.IOException; 

public class Read1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   int count=0;
        int c=0;

        BufferedReader br = Read2.openFile("src/in.txt"); 
            String line; 

                while ((line = Read2.readLine(br)) != null) 
        { 
            for (char letter : line.toCharArray()) 
            {       if (letter == '0')
            {
                count++;
            }
            if (letter == '1') {
                c++;
            }

            } 


        }

                System.out.println("Number of Zeros:" +count);
                System.out.println("Number of ones:" +c); 
}
}
```

Here is the output:

> Number of Zeros:14
>
> Number of ones:16

Thank you all for you help.